# Storing mac addresses and device names listed in a text file into a struct array using C

Tags: arrays, c, fopen, fgetc

I am trying to take a list of MAC Addresses and Device names from a text file and store them in an array called list;

```
struct list {
    char ch; 
    char a[2], b[2], c[2], d[2], e[2], f[2], g[2], alias[32]; //chars a-g are supposed to be a maximum of two characters long to store the different segments of the mac addresses, and the alias stores the device name up to 32 characters. 
};
```

The main function here, as of right now is supposed to open the file "Inet.txt" and read each character individually using "char cur = fgetc." The function then assigns the different parts of the MAC address to  its corresponding position in chars a-g of the list struct, and the alias char if the function goes more than 2 chars without reaching a ":" or a " ". The length of the current char is represented by the variable k, which increases every time the program detects a letter or a number, and is reset to -1 every time variable 'cur' is assigned to something. There is also an array "struct list *head[32]; " which stores each line separately, the line number being identified by the variable "int i", which increases by one every time "cur == '\n'" starting at "int = 0." The main function is as follows;

```
int main() 
{

    FILE *fp;
    char cur, temp[32], temp2[32], p;
    struct list *head[32]; 
    head[0]=(struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    int num = 0, d, data, devices, i = 0, j = -1, k = -1, l = 0; 
    char arr[100][2];

    int count = 0; 
    //head = current = NULL;
    fp = fopen("Inet.txt", "r");

    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file."); 
    }

    while((cur = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
       //stringchecker(cur)!=0
        if((cur >= 48 && cur <= 57)||(cur >= 97 && cur <= 122)||(cur >= 65 && cur <= 90))
        {
           k++; //counter for temp array size
           
           if(cur >= 97 && cur <= 122)
           {
               temp[k] = cur-32; 
           }
           else
           {
               temp[k] = cur;
           }
           if(k>1)
           {
            strncpy(temp2, temp, k+1);
            temp2[k+1] = '\0';
            aloc(&head[i],temp2,7);
            // k = -1; 
           }
        }
        else if(cur == ':')
        {
            if(count == 0)
            {
                strncpy(temp2, temp, 2);
                temp2[2] = '\0';
                aloc(&head[i],temp2,count);
            }
            else if(count == 1)
            {
                strncpy(temp2, temp, 2);
                temp2[2] = '\0';
                aloc(&head[i],temp2,count);
            }
            else if(count == 2)
            {
                strncpy(temp2, temp, 2);
                temp2[2] = '\0';
                aloc(&head[i],temp2,count);
            }
            else if(count == 3)
            {
                strncpy(temp2, temp, 2);
                temp2[2] = '\0';
                aloc(&head[i],temp2,count);
            }
            else if(count == 4)
            {
                strncpy(temp2, temp, 2);
                temp2[2] = '\0';
                aloc(&head[i],temp2,count);
            }
            else if(count == 5)
            {
                strncpy(temp2, temp, 2);
                temp2[2] = '\0';
                aloc(&head[i],temp2,count);
            }
            count++;
            k = -1; 
        }
        else if(cur == ' ')
        {
            strncpy(temp2, temp, 2);
            temp2[2] = '\0';
            aloc(&head[i],temp2,6);
            k = -1; 
        }
        else if(cur == '\n')
        {
            printf("\n%s:%s:%s:%s:%s%s\nALIAS: %s", (*head[i]).a,(*head[i]).b,(*head[i]).c,(*head[i]).d,(*head[i]).e,(*head[i]).f,(*head[i]).alias);
            exit(0);
            devices++;
            data++;  
            count = 0;
            num = -1; 
            i++;  
            j = -1; 
            k = -1; 

           
           head[i]=(struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
           //exit(0); 
        }       
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The "aloc()" function assigns the current char up to 16 characters to a-g or alias depending on the value of the variable count, which is a parameter of this function. The aloc() function is as follows;

```
void aloc(struct list **head, char ch[16], int count) //assigns ch value to specific variable of the current head based on the value of count 1-7
{
     if(count == 0)
     {
        strncpy((*head)->a,ch, 2);
     }
     else if(count == 1)
     {
        strncpy((*head)->b,ch, 2);
     }
     else if(count == 2)
     {
        strncpy((*head)->c,ch, 2);
     }
     else if(count == 3)
     {
        strncpy((*head)->d,ch, 2);
     }
     else if(count == 4)
     {
        strncpy((*head)->e,ch, 2);
     }
     else if(count == 5)
     {
         strncpy((*head)->f,ch, 2);
     }
     else if(count == 6)
     {
        strncpy((*head)->g,ch, 2);
     }
     else if(count == 7)
     {
        strncpy((*head)->alias,ch, 16);
     }
}
```

The input text file "Inet.txt" is as follows;

```
A0:FB:C5:44:b8:45 PLATTE
58:24:29:0f:c8:ee JET
F1:C0:11:16:53:1F Wabash
A0:FB:C5:32:15:10 GREEN
33:68:29:a1:b2:3c Charlie
58:24:29:0A:0B:C0 BAKER
GG:01:X0:99:1A:45 FOXTROT
```

The main problem I am having with this code is the variables a-g are not being assigned correctly. When I run the program to only read the first line, I get the following output:

```
A0FBC544B8:FBC544B8:C544B8:44B8:B8
ALIAS: PLATTE%
```

When the output should be:

```
A0:FB:C5:44:B8
ALIAS: PLATTE
```

I am not sure which line is causing the entire mac address to be assigned to char a of the current list. I will post the code as I have it in its entirety here to avoid confusion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

struct list {
    char ch; 
    char a[2], b[2], c[2], d[2], e[2], f[2], g[2], alias[32]; 
};
void aloc(struct list **head, char ch[16], int count)
{
     if(count == 0)
     {
        strncpy((*head)->a,ch, 2);
     }
     else if(count == 1)
     {
        strncpy((*head)->b,ch, 2);
     }
     else if(count == 2)
     {
        strncpy((*head)->c,ch, 2);
     }
     else if(count == 3)
     {
        strncpy((*head)->d,ch, 2);
     }
     else if(count == 4)
     {
        strncpy((*head)->e,ch, 2);
     }
     else if(count == 5)
     {
         strncpy((*head)->f,ch, 2);
     }
     else if(count == 6)
     {
        strncpy((*head)->g,ch, 2);
     }
     else if(count == 7)
     {
        strncpy((*head)->alias,ch, 16);
     }
    

}
int main() 
{

    FILE *fp;
    char cur, temp[32], temp2[32], p;
    struct list *head[32]; 
    head[0]=(struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    int num = 0, d, data, devices, i = 0, j = -1, k = -1, l = 0; 
    char arr[100][2];

    int count = 0; 
    //head = current = NULL;
    fp = fopen("Inet.txt", "r");

    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file."); 
    }

    while((cur = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
       //stringchecker(cur)!=0
        if((cur >= 48 && cur <= 57)||(cur >= 97 && cur <= 122)||(cur >= 65 && cur <= 90))
        {
           k++; //counter for temp array size
           
           if(cur >= 97 && cur <= 122)
           {
               temp[k] = cur-32; 
           }
           else
           {
               temp[k] = cur;
           }
           if(k>1)
           {
            strncpy(temp2, temp, k+1);
            temp2[k+1] = '\0';
            aloc(&head[i],temp2,7);
            // k = -1; 
           }
        }
        else if(cur == ':')
        {
            if(count == 0)
            {
                strncpy(temp2, temp, 2);
                temp2[2] = '\0';
                aloc(&head[i],temp2,count);
            }
            else if(count == 1)
            {
                strncpy(temp2, temp, 2);
                temp2[2] = '\0';
                aloc(&head[i],temp2,count);
            }
            else if(count == 2)
            {
                strncpy(temp2, temp, 2);
                temp2[2] = '\0';
                aloc(&head[i],temp2,count);
            }
            else if(count == 3)
            {
                strncpy(temp2, temp, 2);
                temp2[2] = '\0';
                aloc(&head[i],temp2,count);
            }
            else if(count == 4)
            {
                strncpy(temp2, temp, 2);
                temp2[2] = '\0';
                aloc(&head[i],temp2,count);
            }
            else if(count == 5)
            {
                strncpy(temp2, temp, 2);
                temp2[2] = '\0';
                aloc(&head[i],temp2,count);
            }
            count++;
            k = -1; 
        }
        else if(cur == ' ')
        {
            strncpy(temp2, temp, 2);
            temp2[2] = '\0';
            aloc(&head[i],temp2,6);
            k = -1; 
        }
        else if(cur == '\n')
        {
            printf("\n%s:%s:%s:%s:%s%s\nALIAS: %s", (*head[i]).a,(*head[i]).b,(*head[i]).c,(*head[i]).d,(*head[i]).e,(*head[i]).f,(*head[i]).alias);
            exit(0);
            devices++;
            data++;  
            count = 0;
            num = -1; 
            i++;  
            j = -1; 
            k = -1; 

           
           head[i]=(struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
           //exit(0); 
        }       
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I initially tried writing this program using linked lists, but I thought it would be easier to keep track of an array of list structs for use later in my program. However I keep getting the same problem with my output. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `cur >= 48`?!?!  **Don't** use magic numbers.  Use the actual character values such as `'A'`.  Or better yet, use standard, **portable** functions such as `isalpha()`.

Comment: When you want to print the structure fields `a`, `b`, etc as strings using format specifier `%s`, you have to increase their size to (at least) 3 and append a `'\0'` after the two characters. Note that `strcnpy` does **not** append a `'\0'` if the string is longer than the specified limit.

Comment: Why don't you just store them in an `int64_t` with "%x"?

Answer (score 2):

If you remove `exit(0);` from the block here

```
else if(cur == '\n')
{
    printf(/* ... */);
    exit(0);
    devices++;
    data++;  
    count = 0;
    /* ... */
```

then this program *appears* to work<sup>1</sup>.

I say "appears" because this program invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) by printing non null-terminated buffers with the [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) specifier `%s`.

You need to either specify a *precision*, being the maximum number of bytes to print, with each `%s` specifier. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[2] = "AB"; /* the null byte is not stored */

    printf("%2s\n", buf);
}
```

Or, you need to ensure your buffers are large enough to store a desired string length plus the null-terminating byte. If you want to store a string of length 2, your buffer must be at least of size 3.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[3] = "AB"; /* the null byte IS stored */

    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

Note that `strncpy` is [notoriously hard to use](https://man.openbsd.org/strncpy.3), as it does not null-terminate the buffer if the *length* of the source string is greater than or equal to the size provided.

---

<sup>1.</sup> You must also change `char cur` to `int cur`. On platforms when `char` is an *unsigned* type, you will not be able to reliably test against the *negative* `int` value of `EOF`. `fgetc` returns an `int` for this reason.

As pointed out in the comments, avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) and instead use the functions found in [`<ctype.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte).

---

If your file contents are predictably formatted, you can just use `fgets` + `sscanf` to read each line. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ADDRS 256

struct address {
    char a[3];
    char b[3];
    char c[3];
    char d[3];
    char e[3];
    char f[3];
    char alias[32];
};

size_t read_macs(struct address *addrs, size_t limit, FILE *f)
{
    char buffer[512];
    size_t n = 0;

    while (n < limit && fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f)) {
        int cv = sscanf(buffer, "%2s:%2s:%2s:%2s:%2s:%2s%31s",
                addrs[n].a, addrs[n].b, addrs[n].c,
                addrs[n].d, addrs[n].e, addrs[n].f,
                addrs[n].alias);

        if (7 == cv)
            n++;
    }

    return n;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s FILENAME\n", *argv);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (!file) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct address store[MAX_ADDRS];
    size_t length = read_macs(store, MAX_ADDRS, file);

    fclose(file);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%s (%s:....:%s)\n",
                store[i].alias, store[i].a, store[i].f);
}
```

```
$ ./a.out Inet.txt 
PLATTE (A0:....:45)
JET (58:....:ee)
Wabash (F1:....:1F)
GREEN (A0:....:10)
Charlie (33:....:3c)
BAKER (58:....:C0)
FOXTROT (GG:....:45)
```